# Tensorflow Object Detection Training Performance

Tags: performance, tensorflow, gpu, object-detection

I am training the ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco network on my own custom classes using the object detection API for tensorflow.

I have used the CPU (i7-6700) and GPU (NVIDIA Quadro K620) to train:

```
Processor   Batch size  sec/step    sec/image
K620        1           0,45        0,450
K620        10          2,22        0,222
i7-6700     1           0,66        0,660
i7-6700     24          9,3         0,388
```

However, the GPU is only about 70% faster than the CPU.
I expected the GPU to be significantly faster.
Is this performance adequate for my hardware or is there something wrong?

Answer (score -1):

maybe  you can try Tensorflow SERVER